# Calling Api within nunjucks file

Tags: nunjucks

I am very newbie in nunjucks.

```
     {% set projects = [ 
        { 
          id: 3,
          dbaslik: "some data 1",
          ddetay: "some data 1",
          src: "img/someimg1.png"
        },
        { 
          id: 4,
          dbaslik: "some data 2",
          ddetay: "some data 2",
          src: "img/someimg2.png"
        },
        .....
      ] %}
      <div class="owl-one owl-carousel owl-theme">
        {% for project in projects %}
          <div class="item-proje"
              id="project-image-slider-{{proje.id}}"
              data-baslik="{{project.dbaslik}}" 
              data-detay="{{project.ddetay}}" >
            <img src="{{project.src}}"/>
          </div>
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
```

This is what my own template which is used to populate some projects. But this is just static data as you see. I have to work with real data. So

I need to call specific project api and get projects, assign project variable and populate them using nunjucks? How can I do that?

Comment: Do you have backend? It is the work for backend to populate data and pass it to template.

Comment: I have not been completed backend yet. Assume that I completed api/project/GetProjects api. I want to invoke this endpoit call within the template (ajax request)l. How can I do that? @LeshaOgonkov

Comment: You can write your own extension, for [example](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/api.html#custom-tags). But it still bad idea to do it within template.

Comment: Thats what I am looking for many thanks @LeshaOgonkov